# How can one determine the chess configuration that maximizes the number of possible moves?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

To clarify, what is the chess-board configuration that would maximize the number of valid moves one player could make on his or her turn? I thought of this question while playing chess, how apropos. I doubt there is a unique configuration, but I am not sure. The problem seems difficult because one must consider every single piece's movement, and the limitations on that piece's movement by other pieces. At any rate, I appreciate any thoughts, hints, or solutions.

Comment: Is promoting to a knight considered a different move from promoting to a queen?

Comment: I think it can't be unique, because you could swap the color of all pieces(and also which player will move next) to get a configuration with the same number of moves available.

Comment: I agree, I think we could forget the uniqueness...but I would consider all promotion as one move (if you don't like that we can add those at the end)

Comment: Curious question.  But could you clarify what the conditions on the board are?  Must the position be reachable in a legal chess game?  Or can we just place pieces anywhere on an 8x8 board (e.g. 30 white queens and nothing else)?

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones : I meant in accordance with the unfolding of a legal game on an 8x8 board, assuming no pieces get captured. However, I like your second variation as well (just placing pieces randomly on the board).

Answer (score 3):

If just the major white pieces are placed on the board, there is an almost-unique 100 move solution.  There are many variations, and a couple of dozen of them are given in [Guide to Fairy Chess](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486226875) by Anthony Dickins. Some of these are also given in Martin Gardner's Sixth book.

These are known as construction tasks.

Comment: Some of those positions from Dickins's *Guide to Fairy Chess* were posted in answer to [this question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/maximum-possible-movement-in-a-turn) on chess.stackexchange, e.g., a legal position with all 32 men and 99 possible moves. Also, a position from actual play with 79 possible moves.