# Counting "isomorphism-classes" of configurations of pieces which 'maximize' the possible movesets.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, optimization, chessboard

Similar question: [How can one determine the chess configuration that maximizes the number of possible moves?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346975/how-can-one-determine-the-chess-configuration-that-maximizes-the-number-of-possi)

Say you have an $8 \times 8$ chessboard with only 8 white rooks (don't want to worry about capturing).

What is the best possible configuration (best in the sense that it maximizes the total number of possible moves on move 1)? I believe it is is with rooks all along the diagonals. This way, each rook can move $7$ units total horizontally and $7$ units total vertically as no piece is obstructing any other. So it will be $(2 \times 7) \times 8$.

Now, another obvious possible configuration is to just put the rooks on the other diagonal. Are there other configurations? Is there a way to set this problem up with group theory in a more general setting where we have some fixed number & type of pieces, and wish to count the number of initial configurations maximizing the possible movesets?

Comment: Any rook in any position has at most $14$ possible moves, so your configuration is certainly a maximum. A configuration is a maximum if and only if no rook attacks any other, i.e., no two rooks share a row or column. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Comment: Very nice! So there are $8!$ possible configurations. Is there a similar result if there are $8$ bishops instead of rooks?